# Octave permute arrays

Tags: matlab, octave

Hey everybody I am messing a little bit using octave and I run into a problem, having:

a = [1,2,3]
b= [4,5,6]

I would like to create a function so that:

n choosees the number of b elements

```
n = 0
result = a1*a2*a3 --> 1*2*3
----
n=1
result = b1*a2*a3+a1*b2*a3+a1*a2*b3 --> 4*2*3+1*5*3+1*2*6
----
n=2
result = b1*b2*a3+b1*a2*b3+a1*b2*b3 --> 4*5*3+4*2*6+1*5*6
----
n=3
result = b1*b2*b3 --> 4*5*6
```

It has to support other sizes rather than 3

how could I do this?

---

edit 1

so far I was able to generate all possible pairs using:

```
var1 = [1,4]
var2 = [2,5]
var3 = [3,6]

[x y z] = ndgrid(var1,var2,var3);
cartProd = [x(:) y(:) z(:)];
```

this generate me:

```
    cartProd =
   1   2   3
   4   2   3
   1   5   3
   4   5   3
   1   2   6
   4   2   6
   1   5   6
   4   5   6
```

which are all the possible combinations, my problem is how to be able to filter them by the number of componnents they use from each array

Comment: What have you tried so far? Do you have any code that you could post? See the [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) article.

Comment: yes I was able to make all combinations using ndgrid but I dont really know how to filter them, furthermore I dont even know if I am heading the right direction

Comment: When `n=0` or `n=3`, why is the result not `a1*a2*a3+a1*a2*a3+a1*a2*a3` or the equivalent with `b1/b1/b3`? It seems like a different approach when only using one of the vectors.

Comment: Because I can only make 1 possible combination with n = 0 where all the a are a1 a2 a3. When I have n = 1, I have 3 different possibilities, take b1, b2 or b3 so all my combinations are [b1,a2,a3] [a1,b2,a3][a1,a2,b3] if I have n = 3, I only have 1 possibility which is take all b

Answer (score 0):

I finally fixed for my self, I used some simple matrix operations in order to make it:

```
%I make a vector with all 0 of the size of a or b
multiply_vect = zeros(size(a));
% 0 0 0

%I change to 1 n elements of the vectors (the elements I want from B)
n = 2
multiply_vect(1:n) = 1;
% 1 1 0

%I make all posible unique permutations with the elements of the vector
multiply_matrix = unique(perms(multiply_vect), 'rows');
% 1 1 0
% 0 1 1
% 1 0 1

%In order to get the bs that I want I multiply each component of my multiply_matrix with b
b_matrix = multiply_matrix .* b
% 4 5 0
% 0 5 6
% 4 0 6

%I do the same with a but multiply it with the complementary of the matrix
a_matrix = ((1-multiply_matrix) .* a)
% 0 0 3
% 1 0 0
% 0 2 0

%I just have to add both matrix component by component
sum_matrix = b_matrix .+ a_matrix
% 4 5 3
% 1 5 6
% 4 2 6

%the only thing left is doing the product of each row and sum all of them
result = sum(prod(sum_matrix'))
% 60
% 120
% 48
% result = 60+120+48 = 228
```

---

```
% code together all together:
a = [1,2,3];
b = [4,5,6];
n = 2;

multiply_vect = zeros(size(a));
multiply_vect(1:n) = 1;
multiply_matrix = unique(perms(multiply_vect), 'rows');
result = sum(prod(((multiply_matrix .* b) .+ ((1-multiply_matrix) .* a))'));
```